# Comments that are copied and posted looks weird

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

When copying a comment and it has a single or double quote in it, they are not displaying properly when pasted e.g.

`@Jeff: How can this be declined with no comment whatsoever? It&#39;s not that this is difficult to implement and definitely would make the user experience better!`

And

`Making the comment separator line slightly bolder when there are hidden comments &quot;behind&quot; it hardly qualifies as adding more UI clutter.`

This happening on the Android phone and tablet app

Comment: Example: it's a nice day. "Something else"

Comment: How do you copy the comment? Is the text selectable or do you do it via some menu of the app itself?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just tap the comment and the options: Upvote, Reply, Report, View profile and the menu icon comes up, clicking on that shows an option to "Copy text" http://i.imgur.com/39Z1C3F.png

Comment: Nice, the iOS app got a "Copy" option, but it copy the [comment permalink](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245897/comments-that-are-copied-and-posted-looks-weird?noredirect=1#comment804742_245897) to clipboard. No way to copy comment text for "us". Hmm... feature request here we come! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard User error: uses iOS instead of Android. Not a bug, [status-declined].

Comment: [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245900/please-let-me-copy-comment-text-to-clipboard)! I took the liberty to shamelessly copy your screenshot, @Howlin. ;D

Answer (score 3):

HTML entities are the bane of my existence.

This is fixed in the next beta update (1.0.53+), thanks!