# Please let me copy comment text to clipboard

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, ios-app

I just came to know that android app users can copy comment's text:

> [image]

Can we get such option in the iOS app as well? Currently there is only  "Share" option which copy or send the comment permalink.

Comment: I hit this the other day and am now kicking myself that I didn't post it as a feature request. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh, you'll live without the meager 5-30 repz it would give. ;)

Comment: I don't have an ios capable device so I won't vote

Comment: @rene and you let this stop you from using the awesome iOS app?! You can always borrow from a friend/family member... :D (and it would give you a hat! ;))

Comment: @ShadowWizard: geeks borrowing from friends or family? Have you forgotten about emulators?! Another handy way to avoid social contact!

Comment: I thought you can select the comments and copy it right? (Just guessing, if it's wrong I'll delete this comment.)

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 nope, guess because it's not a text element it's not selectable. Ordinary tap opens up a menu and long tapping has no effect. No need to delete the comment, it's not that trivial. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be available beginning in beta version 1.2.0.175.

You should now see "Copy" among the comment options.

[image]

In addition, comments that are copied will preserve formatting when pasted into applications that support it (e.g. Mail.app, Notes.app, etc).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!