# Let me do SOMETHING with a comment link to a deleted question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks, ios-app

In the iOS app, links in comments to deleted posts are a dead-end. The app can't display deleted content even if I have the privilege to view it, but there's also no way to do anything else with the link -- such as copy it or open it in a browser.

Please add one of these options, preferably the latter, for the link itself.

I am aware that [the entire comment can be copied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245900/), but that requires hand-processing the text afterwards to extract the link -- frustrating with even the simplest of comments.

Comment: This would be useful for the Android App too! We get the same issue.

Comment: Just to note, @doppelgreener, I believe they want us to post feature reqs separately for each platform even if the functionality is the same, since there are different teams working on each.

Comment: Same goes for Android app. Workaround I've always used is "open in browser" on the question, find the comment, and click the link.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yeah, probably. I'll follow through with bringing this up separately for the Android App shortly. :) (except I am on my phone at the moment, so typing out a question will be tough)

Comment: How does long press on a link leading to a "Copy" / "Open in Safari" menu sound?

Comment: _Exactly_ what I'm hoping for, @BrianNickel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix will be included in the next release.  Tapping and holding a link in a comment will bring up the following menu.

[image: Screenshot showing comment link options]

Comment: Why don't you just make the app open the question if the user has privilege to see it?

Comment: @Ooker unfortunately the [web services](http://stackapps.com/q/1917/25485) don't yet support it. I don't think there are any roadblocks for that anymore so maybe we can add that in the future.