# Let us do something with links to deleted content (Android app version)

Tags: feature-request, android-app, hyperlinks, deleted-posts

This is an Android app corollary to an iOS app suggestion: [Let me do SOMETHING with a comment link to a deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247149/152515)

As its users know, the Android app doesn't have support for viewing deleted content — even when you have the appropriate privileges. So when there's a link to something deleted, that's a problem: we can't visit it or do much with it. That applies whether the link is in a question, answer, or comment.

Could the Android app let us do something with those links, like open it in a browser or copy the URL at least? Being able to copy the URL of a link rather than visit it is a pretty generally useful feature even outside this scope of links to deleted content.

[Here's a link to something deleted](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53949/ideas-for-new-races), for an example. Most of you won't have the privileges necessary to view it.