# Viewing deleted posts in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, bug, ios-app, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

(I suspect this has been asked before, but I can't find it right now, so I look forward to dupe suggestions.)

On some SE sites, I have privileges to view deleted questions and answers. In the iOS app, some of these posts (particularly comments on them) show up in my Feed. Yet when I click them, I get a blank screen and an error dialog — effectively a 404.

Since I'm authenticated in the app, shouldn't my auth token be enough for the server to allow fetching these posts' content?

Comment: Related: [Let me do SOMETHING with a comment link to a deleted question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247149/let-me-do-something-with-a-comment-link-to-a-deleted-question)